# Get point along a linestring that is two feet away from the first point

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following linestring:

```
SELECT  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-97.83396022 29.98609860,-97.83391790 29.98613790)',4326);
```

I need to add a point between the linestring, which is 2 feet from the first point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html).

Since it takes a proportion of the line, the first step is to compute it: convert 2ft to meters, divide by the length of the line in meters, that you get by casting it to geography.

```
WITH src(geom) AS (values (ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-97.83396022 29.98609860,-97.83391790 29.98613790)',4326)))
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, 2 * 0.3048/ st_length(geom::geography)))
 FROM src;

st_astext
-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-97.8339558996568 29.9861026120389)
```

To create a line from the start that is 2ft long, you can use [`st_lineSubstring`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html) instead

```
SELECT st_lineSubstring(geom, 0, 2 * 0.3048/ st_length(geom::geography))
```

Comment: Thank you, very simplified from what i was thinking... would it be accurate the take the first point with the generated point to create the 2 feet line?    SELECT  ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-97.83396022 29.98609860,-97.8339558996568 29.9861026120389)',4326))    is ST_Length always in meters?

Comment: @yanci see edits for creating a new line. No, the distance is in meters for geography. When using geometry, it is in the CRS unit (degrees in this case, which is meaningless for distances)